# Material UI Autocomplete with multiple prop and dynamic options prop

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm trying to create an autocomplete which allows the user to enter in multiple values. The options are too many so I need to do the filtering on the backend. So for every new value the user types, new options come from the backend.

Getting this warning: "Material-UI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid. None of the options match with...You can use the `getOptionSelected` prop to customize the equality test."

```
 <Autocomplete
   onChange={(_event, newVal) => setValue(newVal)}
   multiple={multiple}
   loading={loading}
   loadingText="Searching..."
   defaultValue={defaultValue}
   options={options}
   filterOptions={(options, _state) => options}
   getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
   getOptionSelected={(option, value) => _.isEqual(option, value)}
   renderInput={(params) => (
     <TextField
     {...params}
     {...textFieldProps}
      onChange={queryChanged}
      inputlabelprops={{ shrink: true }}
      />
    )}
 />
```

I understand why the warning is coming, the older values aren't present in the options for the new query. But is there any way to get rid of this warning? Or Am I approaching this incorrectly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check out my code below,
I treat the `dataFromServer` variable as your real data from server.
When the response arrive you should update options state.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const fakeDataFromServer = [
  { key: 0, value: "example 1" },
  { key: 1, value: "example 2" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // here goes your fetch call
    // when response arrives -
    setOptions(fakeDataFromServer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Example" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks..But what about the multiple prop in Autocomplete. I know how to update the options when data comes back to the server but it doesn't get rid of the warnings since the previous Autocomplete values (when you set multiple, autocomplete value is array) are not present in the new options. Do I make sense?

Comment: Look the additional comment I just added below this supposed to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `id` + `multiple` prop for get it work.

That will be something like that:

```
<Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="tags-standard"
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Example" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
```

Here is working example : [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-violet-csttx?file=/src/App.js:482-754)

Comment: Adding id doesn't get rid of the warning. In your example, imagine if after typing and selecting "example1", the options changed to a list that didn't include "example1", that's the scenario that produces the warning. I'm thinking I should just load all the options from the server and virtualize the options. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and seemed to fix the warning with the code below.  For me, the main missing piece was to only update the option values during a 'change' event within the `onInputChange` property.

```
    onChange={(event, item ) => {
        setValue(item)
        field.onChange(item)
    }}
    onInputChange={async (event, newInputValue) => { 
        // Only update values during 'change' event       
        if (event.type == 'change') { 
            setLoading(true) 
            // Grabs the dynamic options list using 'newInputValue'
            // as the search string
            let results = await getList(newInputValue)    
            setOptions([...results, ...value])
            setInputValue([...newInputValue])
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }}
```

There are a few other nuances with getting this to work correctly, but here is my full working code for reference:

```
export function TextSuggestMulti({ control, register, name, ...props }) {

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState()
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([])
  const [value, setValue] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(open && options.length === 0)
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
        return undefined
    }
    if (inputValue === '') {
        setOptions(value ? [...value] : options)
        return undefined
    }
    if (!options.length) {
        return undefined
    }
    return () => false
  }, [loading, options, inputValue])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!open) {
      setOptions(value ? [...value] : [options])
    }
  }, [open]);

  return (
    <Controller
    name={name}
    control={control}
    render={({ field }) => (
        <Autocomplete
        multiple={true}
        open={open}
        onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
        onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
        control={control}
        filterOptions={(x) => x}
        autoComplete={true}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => (option.email === value.email) }
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        options={options}
        loading={loading}
        renderOption={(props, option, state) => {
            return(<li {...props}><span>{option.name}</span>: [{option.email}]</li>)
        }}
        blurOnSelect
        filterSelectedOptions={true}
        onChange={(event, item ) => {
            setValue(item)
            field.onChange(item)
        }}
        onInputChange={async (event, newInputValue) => {        
            if (event.type == 'change') { 
                setLoading(true) 
                let results = await getList(newInputValue)    
                setOptions([...results, ...value])
                setInputValue([...newInputValue])
                setLoading(false)
            }
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
                {...params}        
                label={`${props.label}`}
                InputProps={{
                    ...params.InputProps,
                    endAdornment: (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                        {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                    </React.Fragment>
                    ),
                }}
            />
        )
        }   
        /> 
    )}
    />
    )
}
```